# GeoPandas: Plot two Geo DataFrames over each other on a map

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, geopandas

I am new to using Geopandas and plotting maps from Geo Dataframe. I have two Geo DataFrames which belong to the same city. But they are sourced from different sources. One contains the Geometry data for houses and another for Census tracts. I want to plot the houses' boundary on top of the tract boundry.

Below is the first row from each data set. I am also not sure why the Geometry Polygon values are on such a different scale in each of these datasets.

1. Houses Data Set
   [House Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me8Bb.png)
2. Tract Data Set
   [Tract Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY04h.png)

I tried the following code in the Jupyer Notebook but nothing is showing up.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
tract_data.plot(ax=ax)
house_data.plot(ax=ax)
```

But an empty plot shows up.

This is my first post. Please let me know what else I can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to set the correct coordinate reference system (crs). More info [here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html)

An easy fix might be

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
tract_data.to_crs(house_data.crs).plot(ax=ax)
house_data.plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked. I am new to GeoPandas and didn't realize the importance of CRS difference between datasets.